# Synaptic requiring too many additional removals?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, synaptic

I installed LLVM out of curiousity some time ago, not using it for anything specific. Today I tried removing it with Synaptic, the same way I installed it. The problem is, marking 'removal' on one of the components, libllvm3.4, asks a slew of other apps, including other core libraries, to be removed.

I experienced something like this, where removing a package also removed libc. What's the cause of this behavior and how do I successfully uninstall libllvm without wrecking my system?

Comment: What was your installation command for LLVM?

Comment: @A.B. I remember installing it with Synaptic, pretty spoiled by its convenience.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem

```
sudo apt-get remove llvm-3.4 llvm
sudo apt-get autoremove
```